# GA4 does not show earlier statistics in custom report

Tags: google, google-analytics-4

Hej,
It seems that even after changing data retention to 14 months, Google's GA4 does not show 14 months back and does not allow me to change dates on a custom report. Does anyone know what might be wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Did you install GA4 14 months ago, or on April 8th? GA4 can only get data back to when you started using it.

Answer (score 2):

the amount of data you see in custom reports (or any reports) ultimately depends on when you created your GA4 property and began collecting data. Did you create the GA4 property in that screen prior to April 2023?

Comment: Yes, it was created in January 2023.